# How can i have a button visible after another button is click in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hi friends can you please help me how can i make a button visable after another button is clicked

Comment: Welcome  , post what have you tried for far ?

Comment: Use an click listener one that tells the other to reveal itself.

Comment: can you please explain in codes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
buttonONE.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonTWO.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
});
```

In layout xml:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonTWO"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
public class YourClass extends Activity{

    Button button1;
    Button button2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the view from your xml
        setContentView(R.layout.xml_layout_name);

        // Locate the buttons in your xml
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        //set listener on button1
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //make button2 visible when button1 is pressed
                button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In xml_layout_name:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```